# Inserting Variable length row in R for a 2D matrix

Tags: r, matrix, transpose, insertion

I have data of the following format

```
Reg_No     Subject
  AA11     Physics
  AA11   Chemistry
  AA12     English
  AA12       Maths
  AA12     Physics
```

I am trying to transform this data into row wise

```
Physics   Chemistry
English       Maths   Physics
```

I know that each student can take maximum of 8 subjects

I am trying to create a matrix that can store the above data as variable rows (each student has different number of subjects)

I have written the following code

```
# read csv file
Term4 <- read.csv("Term4.csv")
# Find number of Students
Matrix_length <- length(unique(Term4$Reg_No))
# Uniquely store their reg number
Student <- unique(Term4$Reg_No)
# create matrix to be inserted as csv
out <- matrix(NA, nrow=Matrix_length , ncol=8) # max subjects = 8 so ncol =8
# iterate to get each reg number's subjects
for (n in 1:Matrix_length) {
    y <- Term4[Term4[,"Reg_No"] == Student[n],]$Subject
    # transpose Courses as a single column into row and insert it in the matrix
    out[n,] <- t(y)
}
```

I am getting the following error

> Error in out[n, ] <- t(y) :
>       number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Could anyone please tell me how to work on this error

Thanks and Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dimension Does Not Match When Populating Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916675/dimension-does-not-match-when-populating-matrix)

Comment: I changed `Course` (in your original code) to `Subject`, as it looks like a typo.

Answer (score 2):

[`reshape()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reshape.html) can do this:

```
df <- data.frame(Reg_No=c('AA11','AA11','AA12','AA12','AA12'), Subject=c('Physics','Chemistry','English','Maths','Physics') );
reshape(transform(df,time=ave(c(Reg_No),Reg_No,FUN=seq_along)),dir='w',idvar='Reg_No');
##   Reg_No Subject.1 Subject.2 Subject.3
## 1   AA11   Physics Chemistry      <NA>
## 3   AA12   English     Maths   Physics
```

This will generate a data.frame with as many columns as are necessary to cover all subjects.

The reason your code is failing is that you've preallocated your matrix with 8 columns, but the RHS of each assignment will only contain as many subjects as the current student `n` has in the original data.frame. R rejects index-assignments whose target length is not divisible by the RHS length (actually for plain vectors it will just be a warning, but for matrices it seems to be an error; regardless, it's probably never the right thing to do).

---

In general, if you ever do need to carry out such a non-divisible assignment, you can do it by extending the RHS to sufficient length by appending NAs. This could be done with `rep()` and `c()`, but there's actually an elegant and easy way to do it using out-of-bounds indexing. Here's a demo:

```
m <- matrix(NA_character_,2,8);
m;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
## [1,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [2,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
m[1,] <- letters[1:3]; ## fails; indivisible
## Error in m[1, ] <- letters[1:3] :
##   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
m[2,] <- letters[1:3][1:ncol(m)]; ## works
m;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
## [1,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [2,] "a"  "b"  "c"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```